How to use Windows Key while playing a game with wasd?
I need to use the Windows key while moving in the game (wasd), so completely disabling it isn’t an option. Does anyone know how to block these unwanted popups and functions but still allow me to use the Windows key when needed during gameplay? Any advice would be really helpful!
Thanks!
Research
User Ayoes posted this:
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0
#SingleInstance Force

LWin:: {
    Send "{LWin Down}"
}

LWin Up:: {
     Send "{Blind}{vkE8}{LWin Up}"
}

It's working fine but Windows + A and Windows + W show me another crap.
I was trying to block it but it's disabled walking in the game in two directions.
Solution for Windows + W
I deleted Widgets using PowerShell, Windows + W is now free from action.
Get-AppxPackage MicrosoftWindows.Client.WebExperience | Remove-AppxPackage

How to block Action Center when I'm pressing "Windows + A"?
I tried:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer

called NoWinKeys for Windows 11
I even installed Group Policy Editor and make changes there but I have Windows 11 Home and I'm thinking that this will work only with Windows 11 Pro.

For what purpose do you need to use the Win key during gaming? Can you list the specific popups you want to not see?

What are you attempting to use the Windows key, in my experience, Windows while a full screen application is running sort of silences the Windows key especially while in Game Mode.

I was playing in Project Zomboid game on Mac (1900h), I used to use key in this place for in game VoIP. It's hard for me to switch my behavior now on Windows. I need to press VoIP while moving (wasd).
Game is on the full screen and Windows is in the Game mode.
I spended a few hours searching for a free/paid software to block popping up Windows Menu. When I was happy that I have the solution (above) I saw that A and W are blocking me now.
I don't have Widows Pro, I can't mess up with Policies.
I changed Windows Registry but nothing is working.

The Windows + A shortcut in Windows opens the Action Center and Windows + W  opens the Widgets panel.

Which registry keys exactly?

It's for Windows 10 I believe - not working
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced
called DisabledHotkeys
For Windows 11 - not working
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer
called NoWinKeys
I even installed Group Policy Editor and make changes there.
I'm started thinking that they blocked every know way for Home version.
People are writing that those changes are working but no one mentioned about Windows version they have.

I even deleted now Widgets using PowerShell, Windows + W is now free from action. Get-AppxPackage MicrosoftWindows.Client.WebExperience | Remove-AppxPackage

Using PowerToys from Microsoft I was able to switch A to "-" and W to "*" and back, but writing in the game chat is hard when I need to use those letters.
Now I can play like I used to play on Mac, but this solution is far from good.
